# Amend FAQ to state that language-agnostic is the default

Tags: support, policy

In the meta question [Is [language-agnostic] an appropriate tag](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132/is-language-agnostic-an-appropriate-tag) the top-voted answer is in favour of eliminating the [language-agnostic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag provided that we make it clear that our intent is that all puzzles are open to all languages by default and if the asker wishes to restrict a question to one language that must be explicit. 3 of the other 4 answers are in favour of eliminating the tag.

The best way to make the intent clear would be the FAQ. So the question is: is there any reason not to add the following to the FAQ, between the current third and fourth bullet-points about **questions**?

> A puzzle or golf challenge is assumed to be open to entries in any language unless otherwise specified.

Ping: there's been no disagreement, but also no actual change in the FAQ in more than a year. Could someone with the ability to make the change implement this?

Comment: Having recently received a bronze badge in a tag which it's widely agreed should not exist, I'm getting quite irritated by the lack of action here and I'm very tempted to delete the tag even without FAQ changes.

Comment: Maybe as a first step we can amend the [tag wiki](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/language-agnostic/info) to add a remark converning the inappropriateness. This way it is more visible to people using the tag. Unfortunately, to be clearly visible we would have to put it into the excerpt - where it doesn't really fit.

Comment: @Howard, done. I've also started deleting the tag, but I'm not going to do all >100 questions at once because that would flood the front page.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with this, and will update the FAQ shortly. However, I want to get some closure on the [compression](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/is-using-external-decompression-legitimate-golfing) thread as well so I can update the FAQ in one go.

I've posted a new thread, [FAQ update ideas](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/447/faq-update-ideas), where I solicit discussion on the above two items. Please feel free to pitch in your opinion there!

Comment: Did this get placed on the back burner? I don't think I see it in the FAQ yet.